# how to implement early stopping in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

```
def train():
# Model
model = Model()

# Loss, Optimizer
global_step = tf.Variable(1, dtype=tf.int32, trainable=False, name='global_step')
loss_fn = model.loss()
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=TrainConfig.LR).minimize(loss_fn, global_step=global_step)

# Summaries
summary_op = summaries(model, loss_fn)

with tf.Session(config=TrainConfig.session_conf) as sess:

    # Initialized, Load state
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    model.load_state(sess, TrainConfig.CKPT_PATH)

    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(TrainConfig.GRAPH_PATH, sess.graph)

    # Input source
    data = Data(TrainConfig.DATA_PATH)

    loss = Diff()
    for step in xrange(global_step.eval(), TrainConfig.FINAL_STEP):

            mixed_wav, src1_wav, src2_wav, _ = data.next_wavs(TrainConfig.SECONDS, TrainConfig.NUM_WAVFILE, step)

            mixed_spec = to_spectrogram(mixed_wav)
            mixed_mag = get_magnitude(mixed_spec)

            src1_spec, src2_spec = to_spectrogram(src1_wav), to_spectrogram(src2_wav)
            src1_mag, src2_mag = get_magnitude(src1_spec), get_magnitude(src2_spec)

            src1_batch, _ = model.spec_to_batch(src1_mag)
            src2_batch, _ = model.spec_to_batch(src2_mag)
            mixed_batch, _ = model.spec_to_batch(mixed_mag)

            # Initializae our callback.
            #early_stopping_cb = EarlyStoppingCallback(val_acc_thresh=0.5)


            l, _, summary = sess.run([loss_fn, optimizer, summary_op],
                                     feed_dict={model.x_mixed: mixed_batch, model.y_src1: src1_batch,
                                                model.y_src2: src2_batch})

            loss.update(l)
            print('step-{}\td_loss={:2.2f}\tloss={}'.format(step, loss.diff * 100, loss.value))

            writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=step)

            # Save state
            if step % TrainConfig.CKPT_STEP == 0:
                tf.train.Saver().save(sess, TrainConfig.CKPT_PATH + '/checkpoint', global_step=step)

    writer.close()
```

I have this neural network code that separates music from a voice in a .wav file.
how can I introduce an early stopping algorithm to stop the train section? I see some project that talks about a ValidationMonitor. Can someone help me?

Comment: From the latest TensorFlow documentation (beta), it's possible to implement early stopping with a custom callback. https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/custom_callback#early_stopping_at_minimum_loss

Comment: Well, the link I provided goes directly to an example callback class, `EarlyStoppingAtMinLoss`. An instance of that class can be passed to a model as a callback during training, and it's used during training to stop early when the loss stops decreasing. The example gives the class implementation, and how it's used during training. Furthermore, there's an additional callback mentioned in the docs, "tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping provides a more complete and general implementation". Here's that callback: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping

Answer (score 18):

Here is my implementation of the early stopping u can adapt it:

The early stopping can be applied at certain stages of the training process, such as at the end of each epoch. Specifically; in my case; I monitor the test (validation) loss at each epoch and after the test loss has not improved after `20` epochs (`self.require_improvement= 20`) , the training is interrupted.

You can set the max epochs to 10000 or 20000 or whatever you want (`self.max_epochs = 10000`).

```
  self.require_improvement= 20
  self.max_epochs = 10000
```

Here is my training function where I use the early stopping:

def train(self):

```
# training data
    train_input = self.Normalize(self.x_train)
    train_output = self.y_train.copy()            
#===============
    save_sess=self.sess # this used to compare the result of previous sess with actual one
# ===============
  #costs history :
    costs = []
    costs_inter=[]
# =================
  #for early stopping :
    best_cost=1000000 
    stop = False
    last_improvement=0
# ================
    n_samples = train_input.shape[0] # size of the training set
# ===============
   #train the mini_batches model using the early stopping criteria
    epoch = 0
    while epoch < self.max_epochs and stop == False:
        #train the model on the traning set by mini batches
        #suffle then split the training set to mini-batches of size self.batch_size
        seq =list(range(n_samples))
        random.shuffle(seq)
        mini_batches = [
            seq[k:k+self.batch_size]
            for k in range(0,n_samples, self.batch_size)
        ]

        avg_cost = 0. # The average cost of mini_batches
        step= 0

        for sample in mini_batches:

            batch_x = x_train.iloc[sample, :]
            batch_y =train_output.iloc[sample, :]
            batch_y = np.array(batch_y).flatten()

            feed_dict={self.X: batch_x,self.Y:batch_y, self.is_train:True}

            _, cost,acc=self.sess.run([self.train_step, self.loss_, self.accuracy_],feed_dict=feed_dict)
            avg_cost += cost *len(sample)/n_samples 
            print('epoch[{}] step [{}] train -- loss : {}, accuracy : {}'.format(epoch,step, avg_cost, acc))
            step += 100

        #cost history since the last best cost
        costs_inter.append(avg_cost)

        #early stopping based on the validation set/ max_steps_without_decrease of the loss value : require_improvement
        if avg_cost < best_cost:
            save_sess= self.sess # save session
            best_cost = avg_cost
            costs +=costs_inter # costs history of the validatio set
            last_improvement = 0
            costs_inter= []
        else:
            last_improvement +=1
        if last_improvement > self.require_improvement:
            print("No improvement found during the ( self.require_improvement) last iterations, stopping optimization.")
            # Break out from the loop.
            stop = True
            self.sess=save_sess # restore session with the best cost

        ## Run validation after every epoch : 
        print('---------------------------------------------------------')
        self.y_validation = np.array(self.y_validation).flatten()
        loss_valid, acc_valid = self.sess.run([self.loss_,self.accuracy_], 
                                              feed_dict={self.X: self.x_validation, self.Y: self.y_validation,self.is_train: True})
        print("Epoch: {0}, validation loss: {1:.2f}, validation accuracy: {2:.01%}".format(epoch + 1, loss_valid, acc_valid))
        print('---------------------------------------------------------')

        epoch +=1
```

We can resume the important code here :

```
def train(self):
  ...
      #costs history :
        costs = []
        costs_inter=[]
      #for early stopping :
        best_cost=1000000 
        stop = False
        last_improvement=0
       #train the mini_batches model using the early stopping criteria
        epoch = 0
        while epoch < self.max_epochs and stop == False:
            ...
            for sample in mini_batches:
            ...                   
            #cost history since the last best cost
            costs_inter.append(avg_cost)

            #early stopping based on the validation set/ max_steps_without_decrease of the loss value : require_improvement
            if avg_cost < best_cost:
                save_sess= self.sess # save session
                best_cost = avg_cost
                costs +=costs_inter # costs history of the validatio set
                last_improvement = 0
                costs_inter= []
            else:
                last_improvement +=1
            if last_improvement > self.require_improvement:
                print("No improvement found during the ( self.require_improvement) last iterations, stopping optimization.")
                # Break out from the loop.
                stop = True
                self.sess=save_sess # restore session with the best cost
            ...
            epoch +=1
```

Hope it will help someone :).

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, but then How do you call the train function? How do you change the self parameter at call time?

Answer (score 14):

ValidationMonitor is marked as deprecated. it is not recommended. but you still can use it.
here is a example of how to create one:

```
    validation_monitor = monitors.ValidationMonitor(
        input_fn=functools.partial(input_fn, subset="evaluation"),
        eval_steps=128,
        every_n_steps=88,
        early_stopping_metric="accuracy",
        early_stopping_rounds = 1000
    )
```

and you can implement by yourself, here my my implementation:

```
          if (loss_value < self.best_loss):
            self.stopping_step = 0
            self.best_loss = loss_value
          else:
            self.stopping_step += 1
          if self.stopping_step >= FLAGS.early_stopping_step:
            self.should_stop = True
            print("Early stopping is trigger at step: {} loss:{}".format(global_step,loss_value))
            run_context.request_stop()
```

Answer (score 4):

Since TensorFlow version `r1.10` early stopping hooks are available for the estimator API in `early_stopping.py` (see [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.10/tensorflow/contrib/estimator/python/estimator/early_stopping.py)).

For example `tf.contrib.estimator.stop_if_no_decrease_hook` (see [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.10/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/estimator/stop_if_no_decrease_hook))

Answer (score 3):

For a custom training loop with `tf.keras`, you can implement it like this:

```
def main(early_stopping, epochs=50):
    loss_history = deque(maxlen=early_stopping + 1)

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        fit(epoch)

        loss_history.append(test_loss.result().numpy())

        if len(loss_history) > early_stopping:
            if loss_history.popleft() < min(loss_history):
                print(f'\nEarly stopping. No validation loss '
                      f'improvement in {early_stopping} epochs.')
                break
```

At every epoch end, the validation loss is reconrded in a `collections.deque`. Let's assume that `early_stopping` is set to 3. Every epoch, the 4th last loss is compared to the last three losses. If there is no improvement in these 3 losses, then the loop is interrupted.

Here is the full code:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf
from collections import deque

data, info = tfds.load('iris', split='train',
                       as_supervised=True,
                       shuffle_files=True,
                       with_info=True)

dataset = data.shuffle(info.splits['train'].num_examples)

train_dataset = dataset.take(120).batch(4)
test_dataset = dataset.skip(120).take(30).batch(4)


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(info.features['label'].num_classes, activation='softmax')
])


loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
test_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()

train_acc = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
test_acc = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()


opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)


@tf.function
def train_step(inputs, labels):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        logits = model(inputs)
        loss = loss_object(labels, logits)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
    train_loss(loss)
    train_acc(labels, logits)


@tf.function
def test_step(inputs, labels):
    logits = model(inputs)
    loss = loss_object(labels, logits)
    test_loss(loss)
    test_acc(labels, logits)


def fit(epoch):
    template = 'Epoch {:>2} Train Loss {:.4f} Test Loss {:.4f} ' \
               'Train Acc {:.2%} Test Acc {:.2%}'

    train_loss.reset_states()
    test_loss.reset_states()
    train_acc.reset_states()
    test_acc.reset_states()

    for X_train, y_train in train_dataset:
        train_step(X_train, y_train)

    for X_test, y_test in test_dataset:
        test_step(X_test, y_test)

    print(template.format(
        epoch + 1,
        train_loss.result(),
        test_loss.result(),
        train_acc.result(),
        test_acc.result()
    ))


def main(early_stopping, epochs=50):
    loss_history = deque(maxlen=early_stopping + 1)

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        fit(epoch)

        loss_history.append(test_loss.result().numpy())

        if len(loss_history) > early_stopping:
            if loss_history.popleft() < min(loss_history):
                print(f'\nEarly stopping. No validation loss '
                      f'improvement in {early_stopping} epochs.')
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(epochs=100, early_stopping=3)
```

Here is the output:

```
Epoch  1 Train Loss 1.0368 Test Loss 0.9507 Train Acc 66.67% Test Acc 76.67%
Epoch  2 Train Loss 1.0013 Test Loss 0.9673 Train Acc 65.83% Test Acc 70.00%
Epoch  3 Train Loss 0.9582 Test Loss 1.0055 Train Acc 64.17% Test Acc 56.67%
Epoch  4 Train Loss 0.9116 Test Loss 0.8510 Train Acc 63.33% Test Acc 70.00%
Epoch  5 Train Loss 0.8401 Test Loss 0.8632 Train Acc 67.50% Test Acc 76.67%
Epoch  6 Train Loss 0.8114 Test Loss 0.7535 Train Acc 72.50% Test Acc 80.00%
Epoch  7 Train Loss 0.8105 Test Loss 0.8240 Train Acc 68.33% Test Acc 80.00%
Epoch  8 Train Loss 0.7956 Test Loss 0.7855 Train Acc 81.67% Test Acc 93.33%
Epoch  9 Train Loss 0.7740 Test Loss 0.8094 Train Acc 89.17% Test Acc 73.33%

Early stopping. No validation loss improvement in 3 epochs.
```

As you can see, the last best validation loss is at epoch 6, and then there are three losses after that, with no improvement. Then loop was therefore interrupted.